# Rest Api to Kafka Source Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-rest, confluent-rest-proxy

I have to fetch data from **Rest Api** and dump into **Sql Server** using **Apache Kafka**.
how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Http-Source Connector using confluent hub.